# Why wont my model smooth, (I know it's been asked before)

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am working on a spiderman fan film and I got a spiderman model off of the internet, I put all the textures on it and wanted to smooth it, I clicked on the model and clicked shade smooth, (btw I have 3 parts to that model),
any help would be appreciated,
also, when i downloaded the model I saw that it had some wierd texture files and cant figure out what they are, one of them says S and one says ARM,

thank you for any help on both questions.

edit: here is a picture of the texture files, the yellow ones say ARM and the gray ones say S. I will post a picture of the model soon

[these are the textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L5ud.png)
this is the model[image: the model]

Comment: after I clicked smooth nothing happened btw*

Answer (score 0):

Check the modifier stack.  If there is an edge split modifier set to zero, adding smooth shading will have no effect.  (having the edge split works well for a low-poly style.)  if there is one, just remove it.

I believe that the yellow texture is a form of bump map.  if i am correct, it is useless to you in blender, but would be helpful in Unreal Engine.  the grey texture could either be a bump map or a roughness map.

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to work, there aren't any modifiers, thanks for taking the time out of your day to help though! Edit: there aren't any modifiers apart from the armature one*

Comment: does smooth shading work with your other models?

Comment: Yeah it does, I've tried smooth shading with my other models

Comment: Maybe I have found the reason? on the sketchfab page the model also looks the same as the one in blender, but the one in sketchfab looks like it has very flat lighting so it doesnt show the edges, I'm not a pro so dont judge. here is the model link: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/spider-man-homecoming-aa1ec32b74c34bf4b48d87cfc4bedf35

Comment: i have turned down the metallic slider and the specular one and the model is looking better but not the way I wanted it to be. Edit: after I added a light source it got worse but was still better than the metallic version

Comment: I didn't know you downloaded a sketchfab model.  I'm afraid I don't have any experience with sketchfab.  If you have sketchfab, try opening the file in it, and look and see if there is any settings you need to adjust.  (if I am unaware of what sketchfab does, please alert me.)

Comment: The sketchfab model was taken off of a different website, both don't smooth properly, maybe because it is an FBX file? but I can easily convert it, and it still won't smooth, is there a way I could manually smooth the model, without it taking too long, (and without the subdivision surface modifier,  it seems to break the model)

Comment: I don't know.  If all else fails, try looking for a model on blendswap.  It's free, and all the models are blendfiles.

Comment: this probably won't work, but it's something you could try.  Try entering edit mode, pressing **a** to select all, right clicking, and selecting **smooth vertices**.  It's just one of those things that **might** work.

Comment: I've tried that, what happened is that the model started getting spaces in between the vertices, which looks very wierd

Comment: just an idea, have you tried assigning a different material to it?

Comment: the model came without a material, I tried it then, still didn't work, I put the textures, specular map, and normal map on and still the same thing

Comment: I don't know much about importing models from different programs, so I'm afraid I can't help you.  sorry.

Comment: That's alright, but I have noticed something with the model, when I press shade smooth, the model changes very slightly, there are no signs of smoothing but some things do change very slightly